# How do I capture multiple patterns from a line in python?

Tags: python, regex

Data looks like:

```
text textext text a 111.222.222.111(123) -> 22.222.111.111(7895)
txt txt txxt text b 22.111.22.222(8153) -> 153.33.233.111(195)
text text txt txt c 222.30.233.121 -> 44.233.111.111
txt text txt text d 22.111.22.222 -> 153.33.233.111
```

I want to capture a, b, and c along with the two IPs on that line. I do not want the numbers in parentheses that are attached to some of the IPs.

I want my output to look something like this:

```
a 111.222.222.111 22.222.111.111
b 22.111.22.222 153.33.233.111
c 222.30.233.121 44.233.111.111
```

What the code looks like:

```
f=gzip.open(path+Fname,'rb')
for line in f:
    IP_info=re.findall( r'(a|b|c)\s+([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})+[ -> ]+([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})', line )
    print IP_info
f.flose
```

What my out put actually looks like:

```
[('a', '111.222.222.111', '2.222.111.111')]
[('b',  '22.111.22.222', '3.33.233.111')]
```

The two biggest problems I'm having:

1) The second IP in the output is not complete. The first two digits have been truncated.

2) I am not capturing information for "c".

Comment: this is what I use to test my regex's https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that you can use:

```
\b([abcd])\s+([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})(?:\(\d+\))? +-> +([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG8oE6/2)

There are several points of interest here:

- I replaced your `[ -> ]+` with `+-> +` since you meant to match a *sequence* of characters, not just single characters in various order. **Note that `->` in the character class created a range**, from space to `>` and that included special symbols, punctuation, AND *digits*, too. That is why your IPs were partially "eaten".
- Since there are optional numbers in parentheses after an IP, I added an optional non-capturing group `(?:\(\d+\))?` after the first IP
- You did not match `d` in the first capturing group (that I transformed into a character class since I see just single letters - if these are "placeholders", please revert to a group with alternatives - `(a|b|c|d)`).

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zXDxfD):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\b([abcd])\s+([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})(?:\(\d+\))? +-> +([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3})')
test_str = "text textext text a 111.222.222.111(123) -> 22.222.111.111(7895)\ntxt txt txxt text b 22.111.22.222(8153) -> 153.33.233.111(195)\ntext text txt txt c 222.30.233.121 -> 44.233.111.111\ntxt text txt text d 22.111.22.222 -> 153.33.233.111"
for x in test_str.split("\n"):
    print(re.findall(p, x))
```

Output:

```
[('a', '111.222.222.111', '22.222.111.111')]
[('b', '22.111.22.222', '153.33.233.111')]
[('c', '222.30.233.121', '44.233.111.111')]
[('d', '22.111.22.222', '153.33.233.111')]
```

Comment: the regex fu is strong in this one